# C# DataGridView how to select cell programmatically

Tags: c#

This is how I want to display on startup
[image]

Here is my based setup code:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn c0 = new DataColumn("c0");
        DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn("c1");
        DataColumn c2 = new DataColumn("c2");
        DataColumn c3 = new DataColumn("c3");
        dt.Columns.Add(c0);
        dt.Columns.Add(c1);
        dt.Columns.Add(c2);
        dt.Columns.Add(c3);
        dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", "");
        dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", "");
        dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", "");
        dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", "");
        datagridview1.DataSource = dt;
```

Setting 1:

```
        datagridview1[2, 3].Selected = true;
        datagridview1[2, 2].Selected = true;
```

Setting 2:

```
        datagridview1.Rows[3].Cells[2].Selected = true;
        datagridview1.Rows[2].Cells[2].Selected = true;
```

Both settings 1 & 2 yield this result on startup

[image]

Setting 3:
datagridview1.CurrentCell = datagridview1[2, 3];
datagridview1.CurrentCell = datagridview1[2, 2];

and it yields

[image]

All 3 settings failed to deliver top image.  I've tried several solutions here and from google search.  How do I fix this display so I can select any cell programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work by dropping a DataGridView on a form, don't setting any properties of the DataGridView. Try creating a new form as per above.

Code [is here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/closet-code/blob/master/DataGridViewExportTextFile/Form2.cs) to inspect

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TODO
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Shown += Form2_Shown;
        }

        private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.AddRange(new []
            {
                new DataColumn("c0"), 
                new DataColumn("c1"), 
                new DataColumn("c2"), 
                new DataColumn("c3")
            });

            dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", "");
            dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", "");
            dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", "");
            dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", "");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            dataGridView1[0, 0].Selected = false;
            dataGridView1[2, 3].Selected = true;
            dataGridView1[2, 2].Selected = true;

            dt.Rows[2].SetField("c2","Selected");
            dt.Rows[3].SetField("c2","Selected");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your code again, it's not showing active link?  Yes, I did do a drag and drop without modify any of its property.

Comment: I wonder if it's actually the version of VS or dotNET I'm using VS2012 and .NET4.5. What version are you using?

Comment: The reason the link failed was because I removed the form but have placed it back in so now it will work. I did the demo in VS2019, Framework 4.8 but that does not matter, the code will work in VS2022.

Comment: Ok, now I see exactly what you did vs how I did it.  You encapsulated these settings inside an actual event. So I tried various events, they all work.  And it appears your method works too for setting row header.  I previously wasn't able to get that working so this answers that question as well. Anyone searching, the answer to this question is placing settings inside an event.  Thx